# 「批烂斗臭」这个四字词语，除了「批评」强调什么？

Tags: meaning, idioms

为了练习阅读，我有时候看小报新闻因为内容比较简单。在下面关于“逆向种族主义”的文章中我遇到了一个四字词语：「批烂斗臭」。

> 当然，并不是所有西方人都认同这场文化层面的“革命”。很多保守派的白人就认为这场“革命”是偏激和粗暴的，是在通过树立种种“政治正确”的言论牢笼，逼迫人们去接受“革命者”的观念。而倘若拒不服从，就遭到网络暴力的攻击，被“**批烂斗臭**”，甚至会失去工作和前途。
> <sub>[美国白人终于喊出这个词](https://news.sina.com.cn/w/2020-07-18/doc-iivhvpwx6066202.shtml)，2020年07月18日</sub>

我意识到这个四字词语形容一种严厉的批评，在文章的语境里，网友的批评能够影响对象的职业等。「批烂斗臭」显然跟「批斗」有关。

**问题**：「批烂斗臭」这个四字词语，除了「批评」强调什么？

[有道](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%89%B9%E7%83%82%E6%96%97%E8%87%AD)和[百度百科](https://baike.baidu.com/search/none?word=%E6%89%B9%E7%83%82%E6%96%97%E8%87%AD)没有这个词语。我猜：

- 「批」指的是「批评」，
- 「斗」指的是「决斗」或许「争斗」，强调这种批评有具体的后果，
- 「烂」和「臭」表示批评负面的后果（比如失业等）。

Comment: 高赞的答案说得很好。批烂斗臭是并列的动作-结果复合词。而批斗本身也是上世纪革命中产生的词语，一般只用在政治场合。批烂斗臭既不是一般的批评，也不是一般的斗争，是目的极强，群起攻之，不把敌人声名扫地，逐出社会不罢休的那种浩大的攻讦。

Answer (score 5):

> 「批烂斗臭」 就是(把某人)「**批**判」，(并与他)「**斗**争」而使他「又**烂**又**臭**」的意思。

「批斗」就是「批判斗争」 简化合拼而成的单一动词，用此一词就可表达两种有关连的行为。

「烂」指「腐烂」，用以形容名声 ，说某人的名声烂，就是说某人的名声极坏，像是东西腐烂了而崩溃一般。

「烂」除了指「腐烂」，也含有「**破烂**」之意，用以形容(某人或某势力)，遭受重击而破烂，亦即彻厎失败。

「臭」指「发臭」，用以形容名声，说某人的名声臭，就是说某人的名声极差，去到会令人像嗅到臭味而作呕一般的地步。

「烂臭」 就是 「腐烂」，「发臭」简化合拼而成的单一形容词，用此一词就可表达两种有关连的性质。

> *问题：「批烂斗臭」这个四字词语，除了「批评」强调什么？*

「批烂斗臭」强调 「批判和斗争」，而「斗争」在此也是「打击」的代用詞，如你所想一般，是一个十分严厉的词句。

~

「批烂斗臭」是将「批斗」及「烂臭」结合而成的惯用語式句語， 类似的结合手法十分常见，例如：

斩杀 + 尽绝 --> 斩尽杀绝

明暗 + 争斗 --> 明争暗斗

强硬 + 攻打 --> 强攻硬打

*注：本人在此只凭字面上的意义去解释这一个词句，对其政治含意不予置评。*

Answer (score 5):

这种表达方式非常的“文革”化，立刻让人联想起60、70年代大字报批斗的用词作风。

所以，潜台词是当权者煽动、操作民意来打击异己。其目的比单纯「批评」要强烈很多，往往包括肉体打击，带高帽、游街、批斗等等。

如果只是学习中文，建议对这一类政治倾向明显的用词用语小心谨慎、不用少用为好。

Comment: 看到这个标题，我就纳闷，外国人这年头都在看什么 ;)

Comment: @billc.cn 这应该是中国人编辑的文章，OP的链接里面可以看到整篇。

Answer (score 2):

> 大家可能都知道，在最近一段时间里，美国和英国这样的西方国家，除了正在经受新冠肺炎疫情的冲击，还在经历一场反种族主义和性别多元化的“革命”的浪潮。

> 当然，并不是所有西方人都认同这场文化层面的“革命”。很多保守派的白人就认为这场“革命”是偏激和粗暴的，是在通过树立种种“政治正确”的言论牢笼，逼迫人们去接受“革命者”的观念。而倘若拒不服从，就遭到网络暴力的攻击，被“批烂斗臭”，甚至会失去工作和前途。

The topic here is 反种族主义和性别多元化的“革命”.  So, many conservative white people disapprove this “革命” because they think 这场“革命”是偏激和粗暴的，是在通过树立种种“政治正确”的言论牢笼，逼迫人们去接受“革命者”的观念.  If you disagree on it, you would suffer 网络暴力的攻击, 被“批烂斗臭” and even lose your job and future.

“批烂斗臭” is used with a quote mark here because it's from those 革命者's point view, not those conservatives.  They think such opinions(against this 革命) are something '烂' and '臭' and should be 批ed and 斗ed.

烂(rotten) and 臭(stinky) are used metaphorically, referring to something disgusting/devious/etc, which shows strong disapproval.  批斗 denotes 批评斗争 and this dictionary definition defines it well:

> criticize and struggle; criticize and denounce sb. (at a public meeting)

批斗 is a cruel way to correct somebody's wrong doings or believes.  It's often been used in political or religious context.  Here “批烂斗臭” shows how conservatives have been ill-treated by those "反种族主义和性别多元化的革命者".

Answer (score 1):

说下我自己的理解。烂和臭也可以是批斗的对象，批评腐烂的价值观，和恶臭的资本做斗争。烂和臭用来正确化批斗的立场，突出发起者自身的光大伟岸。

Comment: 如果是「去批烂斗臭」那烂和臭也可以是批斗的对象，但 原文中的是「被批烂斗臭」，显示另有宾语，烂和臭则一定是副词